# Why x86 ISA devices cannot perform DMA in to the full 32 bit address space?

Tags: linux-kernel, x86, cpu-architecture, memory-management

As per  `Robert Love` 's  `Linux Kernel Development` , an x86 ISA device cannot perform DMA in to the full 32 bit address space because ISA devices can access only the first 16MB of physical memory(range 0MB-16 MB). Why is that so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The 16-bit ISA bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industry_Standard_Architecture) only has 24 address lines, so it can only encode addresses up to 16MiB. This matches the 80286 CPU for which it was designed (as an extension to the 8-bit expansion bus used with the 8086 and its 20 address lines).

The ISA bus itself was never extended beyond 24 address lines. It was replaced by MCA, EISA, the VESA local bus, and PCI.

Comment: Thanks. If we use PCI or the latest bus technology, can ZONE_DMA exist out of the 0MB-16MB range?

Comment: @FrancM on x86, `ZONE_DMA` is always the ISA DMA zone, *i.e.* limited to 16MiB; `ZONE_DMA32` is the 32-bit DMA zone. Other platforms have different definitions.